# Contar inputs visíveis e ativos no meu formulário

Tags: jquery, html, css

Bom, sei que o `Jquery Validation` faz algo parecido, pois ele so bloqueia um campo requerido, se o mesmo estiver ativo, [vide exemplo](http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/)(Nesse caso, se voce aceita o "Please agree to our policy" ele ativa os 3 `comboBox` debaixo e o `validate` passa a ser ativo pra eles tambem).

Estou usando a função `JQuery` `find` desse jeito:

```
function calc(){
    alert($("#meuForm").find(".form").size());
}
```

No meu formulário coloquei pra ele achar todos campos com a `class="form"`

O meu grande problema é que existem campos invisíveis, e campos inativos, mas mesmo assim ele continua contando eles..... Alguma ajuda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar não entendo a necessidade de definir class="form" para cada campo mas assumindo que é um requisito especial para o pretendido, gostava de referir uma forma que considero mais aceitável utilizando JQuery.

```
$("#meuForm").find('input[type=text]')
```

No entanto e indo de encontro ao solicitado é possivel obter com o ':visible'

```
$("#meuForm:visible").each(....);
```

ou

```
$("#meuForm").not(":visible").each(....);
```

para finalizar coloco ainda uma outra forma de obter todos os campos excepto os 'hidden'!

```
$(":input:not([type=hidden])")
```

Comment: ummmm show @chambelix.... dá pra fazer algo do tipo: `if($("#meuForm").find('input[type=text]:visible')){.....}` ? Se der, já mata meu problema aqui

Comment: $("#meuForm").find('input[type=text]').filter(':visible')... resolvido?

Comment: kkk não.... se possivel, monta um jsfiddle mano, acho que voce não entendeu minha duvida....

Comment: coloquei várias formas de como obter apenas os campos que não são 'hidden' ou por outras palavras que não são visíveis

Comment: A pergunta inicial era... Contar inputs visíveis e ativos no meu formulário... ;/

Comment: ok Marcelo, pensei que seria suficiente colocar as tags...para contar basta colocar o comando length... exemplo numero de campos vísiveis: $("#meuForm").find(":input:not([type=hidden])").length

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17030/discussion-between-marcelo-bonifazio-and-chambelix).

Answer (score 3):

Para obter o número de inputs visíveis e habilitados, levando em conta que você colocou a classe form em todos:

```
alert($(".form:visible").not(":disabled").length);
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/yadvs398/