# Verificar se há itens visíveis dentro de uma div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como verificar se há algum elemento visível ou vice e versa dentro de uma `<div>`?

Eu consigo me virar com jQuery e tentei usando `el.is(':visible')` mas não consegui, pois preciso verificar se todo mundo dentro da `<div>` está oculto.

Comment: Talvez isso ajude: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31934/contar-inputs-vis%C3%ADveis-e-ativos-no-meu-formul%C3%A1rio

Comment: Thiago, aqui não é um fórum é um Q&A recomendo que faça o tour para ver como funciona o site: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour - Não poste a resposta dentro da pergunta ou em comentários. Você pode responder a sua própria pergunta usando o botão "responder" - veja o tour. Veja que postei uma resposta com o que você adicionou na pergunta, se quiser copie e responda novamente e eu apago a minha resposta.

Comment: @ThiagoDiniz por favor formule uma resposta se quiser, assim irei apagar a minha que adicionei somente para a pergunta não ficar com resposta no corpo dela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com o comentário do amigo @marcelobonifazio

O autor conseguiu usando:

```
var divFilho = divPai.find('ul:visible').length;

if(divFilho === 0){
    divPai.hide().addClass('hidden');
}
```