# Pegar nome de todos os campos com a tag required

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Quero pegar o nome de todos os campos com a tag `required` e testar um por um, caso algum deles estiver vazio, insiro o nome em um array.
Essa pergunta se assemelha em algumas coisas com essa [antiga pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31934/contar-inputs-vis%C3%ADveis-e-ativos-no-meu-formul%C3%A1rio) minha, mas o contexto é diferente.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var inputs = [];

  jQuery('input[required]:visible,select[required]:visible').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('erro');
    if (jQuery(this)[0].value == "" || jQuery(this)[0].value == undefined || jQuery(this).prop('checked') == false) {
      jQuery(this).addClass('erro');
      inputs.push(jQuery(this)[0].name);
    }
  });
  console.log(inputs);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="1" required/>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="2" required />
<input type="radio" name="teste" value="3" required />
<input type="radio" name="option" value="4" required />
<input type="radio" name="option" value="5" required style="display:none">
<input type="radio" name="option" value="6" required disabled>
<input type="text" name="teste1" required>
<input type="text" name="teste2" required>
<select name="teste5" required>
  <option></option>
  <option val="1">a</option>
  <option val="2">b</option>
  <option val="3">c</option>
</select>
<input type="teste" name="teste6" required>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Tentei algo do tipo: `jQuery(this)[0].checked==""` mas não funcionou muito bem

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se entendi muito bem, mas seria isso que busca?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var inputs = [];

  jQuery('[required]').each(function() {
    //console.log(this);
    jQuery(this).removeClass('erro');
    if (!jQuery(this).val()) {
      console.log("entrou");
      jQuery(this).addClass('erro');
      inputs.push(jQuery(this).attr('name'));
    }
  });
  console.log(inputs);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="visa" type="radio" name="option" value="visa" required/>
<input id="visa" type="radio" name="option" value="visa" required />
<input id="visa" type="radio" name="teste" value="visa" required />
<input id="visa" type="radio" name="option" value="visa" required />
<input id="visa" type="radio" name="option" value="visa" required style="display:none">
<input id="visa" type="radio" name="option" value="visa" required disabled>
<input type="teste" name="teste1" required>
<input type="teste" name="teste2" required>
<select name="teste5" required>
  <option></option>
  <option val="1">a</option>
  <option val="2">b</option>
  <option val="3">c</option>
</select>
<input type="teste" name="teste6" required>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Se for isso, avise que explico melhor as alterações. Se não for, explique melhor o que está buscando que eu edito minha resposta.

Comment: Consegui achar uma solução rs, tentei explicar na pergunta mas acho que não ficou claro

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio Eu realmente não entendi muito bem o que busca. Mas se achou uma resposta, poste ela que com certeza ajudará outras pessoas. xD

Comment: Sim, vou tentar estruturar melhor a pergunta, e acabar de arrumar a resposta, ai eu posto :)